# Splitting boxplots onto multiple pages

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have some data

```
tmp = data.frame(ID = replicate(25, paste(sample(LETTERS, 7, replace = T), 
                                          collapse = "")),
                 Score = rnorm(1000))
```

I wish to create boxplots of these data using ggplot, but I want to split the boxplots over multiple pages. I then need to extend this to split on a random number. So for example if I had, say, 66 unique IDs and therefore 66 boxplots and I wanted the first 42 to be on one graphics window and the next 24 to be on the next window.

I know that if I create a ggplot object then I can get the structure of that object, but I am just not sure where I should subset it, or if sub-setting would work in this case.

```
p = ggplot(tmp, aes(ID, Score)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
str(p)
```

Comment: I would use `table(tmp$ID)` to help split the data into for plots with a manageable number of levels. You can then set how they appear together using R Markdown / knitr

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'for plots'? Are you saying to create the plots in a loop?

Comment: It's a typo :-) The method I had in mind would involve either a `for` loop, or an easy-to-type function that you could paste several times in a markdown document.

Comment: if you search for `marrangeGrob` you'll find a couple of similar requests and possible solutions